# Find CVE fixed in linux-image-generic

Tags: security, vulnerability

I want to know which CVE is fixed in linux-image-generic, but this information is unavailable in changelog,

```
apt changelog linux-image-generic | cat
```

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that `linux-image-generic` is a meta-package that will always depend on the latest generic kernel image available for your Ubuntu release/version ... You can find out which one it is currently on your system with:

```
apt show -a linux-image-generic
```

... and then use that in the package search field at [CVE reports](https://ubuntu.com/security/cves) to find out about reported CVEs with their status if any and at [Ubuntu Security Notices](https://ubuntu.com/security/notices) to find out about fixed ones.

Search is by the actual package name ... See the reported CVE for the  [`traceroute`](https://ubuntu.com/security/cves?q=&package=traceroute&priority=&version=&status=) package for example which is also discussed on this site at [What exactly traceroute's "CVE-2023-46316" is?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1493779).

**Notice** that `apt changelog package-name` although should have a brief mention of a certain CVE fix related to that package **after** it has been fixed, is not going to necessarily link that fix to a certain CVE by its name although it could be reported beforehand (see the changelog mention for the fix related to the above CVE in [`traceroute`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/traceroute/files/traceroute/traceroute-2.1.3/) for example) ... So, might not be the first goto resource regarding Ubuntu's packages related reported CVEs, but [Ubuntu Security](https://ubuntu.com/security) is.